# Cannot fetch or get channel?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make something that can detect when there is a mention, and that part works, and sending it does too, somewhat. For some reason, **I cannot fetch or get the channel (833856168668561409) in any way.** The bot can view the channel and send messages to it, but it can't seem to find it. I'm not sure what's happening, and I can't find anything that will find an answer for this. Thank you for your time, code is displayed below.

```js
  if (message.guild.id == 793079701929066517) {
    if (message.mentions.members.size) {
        var channel = client.channels.fetch("833856168668561409"); //Get log channel.
              var webhooks = await channel.fetchWebhooks();
              var webhook = webhooks.first();
        await webhook.send(`**Ping detected:**\n${Util.cleanContent(message.content, message)}`, {
                  username: `${message.author.username}`,
                  avatarURL: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`,
                })
      }
  }
```

Comment: Just to confirm, did you try [`ChannelManager#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) - `client.channels.fetch`?

Comment: I believe so. Did not work.

Comment: It seems after I put that in I get this: TypeError: channel.fetchWebhooks is not a function

Comment: Can you update the question with the code using `client.channels.fetch`?

Comment: I changed it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to make the webhook for the channel I was requesting a webhook from.
Basically:

```js
'Bot: I need a webhook for this channel'
'Discord: There is no webhook, so I will give an empty list.'
'Bot: Now I must use this to send a message'
'Bot: I cant...?!?!'

// Basically there is no webhook for it to send with.
```

Answer (score 0):

`client.channels.fetch` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You should `await` the result.

Without `await`, `channel.fetchWebhooks` (`channel` is a `Promise`) returns `undefined` causing the `channel.fetchWebhooks is not a function` error.

```
const channel = await client.channels.fetch('833856168668561409')
```

---

There's no reason to use `var` anymore. Use `const` or `let`.

Comment: `Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.` I fixed that by changing client to bot but now I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Comment: @DeflatedSheep Looks like `webhooks` is an empty collection. You can add a condition to make sure `webhooks.first()` exists before calling `send` on it.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: YOU'RE RIGHT! I FORGOT TO MAKE THE WEBHOOK FOR THE CHANNEL HAHAHAA

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Hi Arun. Thanks for your help. I'm the founder of Hotpot.ai. Would you be open to Node.js consulting? Could you please email info -at- hotpot.ai if you are?  These questions are about creating AI bots to go on Twitter like these: https://twitter.com/hotpothelper. Please let me know when you see this comment so I can delete it. Thanks!